# Meteor saving a line break inputed by the user within the input field

Tags: html, meteor, line-breaks

Is there a package with meteor that can allow me to save a line break within a string inputted by the user? If so, how can this be achieved?

Possibly creating a helper that generates the markdown on keypress which===13?

Comment: Is your input control a textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new line in a textarea will be saved in the database by default (the **\n** character).
After loading the saved text you could either wrap it in a `<pre>` tag which will preserve que \n or convert all \n to `<br>` with a helper